# MSAccess 2010 Forms: Using If and Then Statements

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two text fields on MS Access 2010 Forms, Branch_Name and Branch_Code. I need to have a code or expression in which, when I type the branch code eg: 9001, then Trafalgar Square appears automatically in Branch_Name field. I have 240 branch codes, for which I need to have such a code.

Help please, as it is a self-initiated project in my department.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you may be able to use [DLookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx) for this.  Give that a try, and show us details about any trouble you encounter.

Comment: Please add your try, StackOverFlow cannot reply you for a such an inaccurate question: a collective sanction for Question and Answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off creating a combo box for `Branch_Code` and then set the ***Row Source*** to something like:

```
SELECT Branch_Code, Branch_Name FROM MyTable
```

Then on the `AfterUpdate` event do something like the following:

```
Private Sub txtBranchCode_AfterUpdate()
  If(vba.strings.len(txtBranchCode.value & "") <> 0)then
    txtBrachName.value = txtBranchCode.Column(1)
  Else
    txtBrachName.value = ""
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would try this out tomorrow when I go to office and will share results.

Comment: Why not just set txtBranchCode.value = Nz(txtBranchCode.Column(1),"") ?